# What does this Bessel function integral evaluate to?

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I'm working with a problem where this integral pops up:
$$\int_0^\infty J_\nu(t) \frac{t^{1-\nu}}{\sqrt{t^2 + x^2}} \operatorname{d} t.$$
It is superficially similar to equation [10.22.46 from the DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E46), but the sign of $\nu$ in the exponent is opposite. This can be viewed as a [Hankel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) of $\frac{t^{-\nu}}{\sqrt{t^2 + x^2}}$. Because $J_\nu(t)$ is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) there may be some clever way to use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). The domain of interest has $\nu \ge -\frac{1}{2}$, with particular interest to integers and half integers. $x$ is likewise real and positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Mathematica result:
$$
 \int_{0}^{\infty} J_{\nu}(t) \frac{t^{1-\nu}}{\sqrt{t^{2} + x^{2}}} \operatorname{d}t =
\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \lvert x \rvert x^{-\nu -\frac{1}{2}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}} x I_{\nu -\frac{1}{2}}(x)-\pmb{L}_{\nu -\frac{1}{2}}(x)\right)
$$
for
$$
\Re(\nu )>-\frac{1}{2}\land \Re\left(x^2\right)>0
$$

Comment: What is $\mathbf{L}_{\nu-\frac{1}{2}}(x)$?

Comment: The result is the formula 6.564.2 in Gradshteyn-Ryzhik. The function $L$ is the (modified) Struve function.